# sqlserver express database copy options

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

Why can I not see an **option** for copying database objects when I `right click > tasks` on my database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS Sql Server Express doesn't come with SSIS which is what you will need to import/export objects out of your database.

You can also manually script this process. One way is to use BCP (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)

Comment: Agreed.  The Import and Export options require a for-pay edition like Standard or better.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Red Gate [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm) and [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Compare/index.htm).

You can download the trial and use them to build a script that will dump your objects to a .sql file.